# CodeClimate report in GitLab for c++ not showing

Tags: c++, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to activate the code climate report for merge requests pipelines in GitLab. The CodeClimate analyser is running but there are not shows any warnings when I add some bad code. There might be some configuration which I have missed.

I have added the following to my .gitlab-ci.yml file in the project rot folder:

```
include:
    - template: Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml
```

And I have added the .codeclimate.yml file looks like this:

```
plugins:
  cppcheck:
    enabled: true
    config:
      check: all
      language: c++
      stds:
        - c++14
        - c++17
```

The build job completes with the following lines at the end of the log:

```
f47a75dcba39: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:c8afb8c2037f7b9c5c9ae198aff00b1cf80db11d3591fbe89dfb3c69192663f1
Status: Downloaded newer image for codeclimate/codeclimate:0.72.0
WARNING: A new version (v0.85.3) is available. Upgrade instructions are available at: https://github.com/codeclimate/codeclimate#packages
Uploading artifacts...
gl-code-quality-report.json: found 1 matching files 
Uploading artifacts to coordinator... ok            id=227197201 responseStatus=201 Created token=4xyzSXzN
Job succeeded
```

What could be wrong here, since the merge request doesn't show any CodeClimate report?

In GitLab I have created one merge request with the configuration change (merging into master). And one merge request with some bad code, based on the first merge request with the configuration (merging into master).

The bad code:

```
int non_used_int;

int non_initialized_int;

int dummy = non_initialized_int;





// empty for loop
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {

}
```

And a final note: I am using the shared GitLab runners provided by GitLab.

*Guides I have followed:*

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/code_quality.html
- https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/cppcheck

Comment: please add gitlab runner version run `gitlab-runner -v`

Comment: @NaorTedgi It is shared gitlab runners... so I would expect it to be the newest version :)

Comment: a shared runner can be run locally from your pc also. and then it depends on the version you install its a best practice for debugging your `.giltab-ci.yml` file using the shell excuter, instead of pushing a new commit in view the pipeline

Comment: @NaorTedgi Interesting. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: after the pipeline is finished do you have a `Job artifacts` section inside the pipeline summary?

Comment: No I don't see anything about artifacts. I also just checked the runner version which was: 11.11.2 at the moment i wrote the question and is now: 12.0.0-rc1

Comment: can you upload a screenshot of the `pipeline` summary page from the left menu`CI/CD` -> `Jobs` and the last one who passed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195250/discussion-between-7heviking-and-naor-tedgi).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[TLDR SCROLL DOWN TO SOLUTION]**

you have to gain more control on your **gitlab.yml** file the best way to do so is by installing the `gitlab-runner` locally

- [Install GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/)
- [Install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/install/)

after your gitlab-runner and docker are properly installed  on your local machine

run it locally on your repository (you have to be inside your repository folder in the same path as .gitlab.yml file) 
 start with a minimal .gitlab.yml file

the command to run locally is

`sudo gitlab-runner exec docker <Task-Name>`

for example lets take this minimal gitlab.yml file

```
image: walberla/cppcheck

cppcheck:
  script:
    - cppcheck --error-exitcode=1 .
```

the command will be

`sudo gitlab-runner exec docker cppcheck`

and the output will look like this :

[image]

now if everything works fine to follow the gitlab pipeline output for example i made 
a simple gitlab repo only containing your example file and `gitlab.yml`

https://gitlab.com/Naor-Tedgi/cpp-ci-runner/-/jobs/235981732

now we gain control on all the process you could see exactly what is going inside the ci and run the same process locally for example in the pipeline the
 image they using is `docker:stable-did` after runing the same steps you will understand what you are missing

keep in mind that because you are using docker in docker you will need to add `--docker-privileged`

```
 sudo gitlab-runner exec docker <Task-Name> --docker-privileged
```

**[UPDATE! 20/06/19]**

after our chat talk, and further investigation
I created a simple example using code quality and the same gitlab.yml as mention above an got the same problem

https://gitlab.com/Naor-Tedgi/cpp-ci-runner/-/jobs/235981732

[image]

artifacts links [404] : https://gitlab.com/Naor-Tedgi/cpp-ci-runner/-/jobs/235981732/artifacts/keep

we found out there is an open issue with gitlab code quality artifacts since yesterday

> Code Quality no 'Download' option and 'Keep' results in 404

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/12274

and need to follow up this thread for more information

**[SOLUTION]**

[7heviking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012636/7heviking)

after more forth investigation of the template **Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml**

in the last commit  from 6 days ago that changes this file, 
they change the `paths` property to `reports`

[image]

as shown here

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/commit/f0773d9ec8628e301c5a673ff7b7c2193569395d

taking the previous file with the paths artifacts fix the problem with the 404

**steps for fixing the issue:**

- wait for Gitlab To fix this
- or you can use codeclimate without the template file 
  as i used in my example project

https://gitlab.com/Naor-Tedgi/cpp-ci-runner/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

this is the result of how it should look after uploading artifacts works

https://gitlab.com/Naor-Tedgi/cpp-ci-runner/-/jobs/236205051

Comment: This solves the problem by getting the CodeClimate report into GitLab. However, the original question still isn't. solved as the report still doesn't show in the merge request. I don't see it in your example repository either.

Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/Naor-Tedgi/cpp-ci-runner/-/jobs/236205051 uploaded in artifact section

Comment: Yes, I see it on the right side :) 
But the analyse should also show in the merge request... as I remember.

Comment: Like this page shows: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/code_quality.html

Comment: This is the meagre request page i pushed directly into master branch to see this menu you need to push new branch to the remote

Comment: Now I do see the report inside of the merge request. However, it says: "No changes to code quality". I would expect that the bad code from the question would yield some warnings in CodeClimate. Am I wrong or are there something wrong with the code climate configuration file (.codeclimate.yml)?

Comment: upload the log  file from the last run usually if the file is not loaded , thus lines will appear `Generating .codeclimate.yml...
Config file .codeclimate.yml successfully generated.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195329/discussion-between-7heviking-and-naor-tedgi).

Comment: Sorry, any news on this?